# what are the ways of customizing autocomplete results?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement autocomplete plugin from jqueryUI on my client's website, but I find it very difficult to make it look and behave the way I want. I'm not experienced in using jqueryUI at all and its code and css is way too complicated for me. Apart from changing colors etc. anything "bigger" is beyond my grasp but default settings do not work well with the website.

To give you example what I need to achieve - I need to set various sizes depending on screen size, I need the whole list to be in position relative to the element that is fixed only at times (right now when the list is displayed and someone scrolls the document, it goes up and down with the whole document, even though the input form is actually in fixed position). And there's more.

So to question - I was wondering - is there any way to get from the plugin just the information it generates in the form of plain list of suggested items? Then I could make my own code that will display and behave the way I want. And if it's not that simple - maybe someone knows some other plugin who works like autocomplete but gives back just the raw information that we can do anything with.
Thank you for suggestions and ideas.
Cheers

Comment: can you please post a JSFiddle, so it will be easy to understand your problem.

Comment: I like reading code more than reading a novel.